# How do I allow incoming connections to my node running on Tor?

Tags: monerod, tor

I have a node running on a Pine64, and allow incoming connections to it by forwarding port 18080 on my router. Checking status on it would show 8(out)+x(in) connections, with x usually hanging around 30 or so.

Until Kovri is ready, I thought I would try running the node on Tor, and so followed the instructions at https://github.com/monero-project/monero#using-tor to run using torsocks, and seems to be working. However, I now always get 8(out)+0(in) connections. I'm guessing that is happening because incoming connections are using a different ip address that is not forwarded on my router. Any suggestions as to how to allow incoming, or is this the price you pay for using Tor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monero does not have an hidden service as Bitcoin does. This would be needed in order for an external client to connect via Tor. Allowing clients to connect via clearnet would need code changes in Monero so outgoing connections could be made via Tor, while listening for incoming connections could be made normally. Alternatively, allowing proxy connections should also work. None of these things are done in monerod.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Was fun to play with Tor, but I'll switch back to non-Tor wrapped daemon to allow incoming connections. Can't wait for Kovri.